# NPE in initialize

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

After reading [introduction_to_fxml](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) I got an impression that an initialize method can be used as spring's afterPropertiesSet or EJB's a @PostConstruct method - that is expected all member variables set when it is invoked. But when I tried I got NPE. The code I tried looks like following.

Main app:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/myapp.fxml"));///MAIN LOAD

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 240);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/myapp.css");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("my app");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(); }
}
```

myapp.fxml:

```
...
<VBox fx:id="root" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" >
       <ControlA>
           <SomeClass>       
           </SomeClass>
       </ControlA>
</VBox>
```

ControlA.java:

```
@DefaultProperty("aproperty")
public class ControlA extends StackPane {
   private SomeClass aproperty;

     public ContentPane(){
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/controls/ControlA.fxml"));
            fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
            fxmlLoader.setController(this);

            fxmlLoader.load();//ControlA LOAD

        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public void initialize() {
         //aproperty is null here, called from ControlA LOAD
    }

   //aproperty get/set
   public void setAproperty(SomeClass p){//it is called from MAIN LOAD
   ....
}
```

The component's initialize method is called from its load method and its property is being set from parent's load method which is called later. And it looks understandable, a component's property values can't be constructed until parent fxml is read. But if so, what is best practice to init a component before it will be used and after all the props were initialized?

Best regards, Eugene.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the [Initializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) interface in a controller.  I was under the impression that this was for controllers only.